# StringTokenizer, forget a deliminiter

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I'm currently stringtokenizing the following line.

```
2014-03-24 19:11:42.838  7611.668 UDP       192.168.0.15:5353  ->      224.0.0.251:5353        53     5353    12
```

I actually want the "2014-03-24 19:11:42.838" as a token itself but I cant seem to figure out how to get the stringtokenizer to skip the space in between.

Comment: Does it have always the same length up to the miliseconds? You can substring it if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can read two tokens and then concatenate them
2. it seems that there is two spaces after token you want. If it's true you can use `indexOf` to get index of two spaces and then use substring.
3. You can use `Scanner.next(pattern)` to get this string. all you need is correct pattern

Comment: Thanks for all the answers,ended up going with the concatenation. Cheers!